# How do people typically develop Haskell modules?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Sorry for the somewhat general question. I am new to Haskell, and I am the type of person who learns by diving into a problem and figuring out the required pieces as I go along. So, I've started developing a Haskell module that aims to do simple linear regression. Here is my directory setup:

```
mymod/
- mymod.cabal
- src/
-- MyMod/
--- Linear.hs
--- Linear/
---- Regression.hs
--- Data.hs
--- Data/
---- Examples.hs
- tst/
```

My cabal file looks like this:

```
library
  exposed-modules:     MyLib.Linear, MyLib.Linear.Classifier, 
                       MyLib.Data, MyLib.Data.Examples
  build-depends:       base == 4.6.*
  hs-source-dirs:      src
```

Right now, I am writing the `Examples` module, which is essentially a CSV file parser. That looks like this:

```
module Exampels (load) where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative

examples = line `endBy` eol
line = cell `sepBy` (char ',')

cell :: GenParser Char st Double
cell = rd <$> many1 (noneOf ",\n")
    where rd = read :: String -> Double

eol = char '\n'

load :: String -> Either ParseError [[Double]]
load input = parse examples "(unknown)" input
```

This was the first piece of the system that I wrote. I tested this by using `ghci` and `:l Examples.hs` from `mylib/src/MyLib/Data/` followed by `load "5\n"` and verified the result. Now I want to start writing the regression logic, but I want to test this code in conjunction with the CSV parser I already wrote. How to people typically go about testing code like this?

For instance, in Java I would typically create a new package with a class that has a main method in it. With Java, this is straight forward to me because I understand how the classpath works and can direct the compiler to look for my classes that I want to run. How do I do this in Haskell?

Thanks!

Comment: `ghci` searches for modules relative to your current directory, so a quick and easy trick is to just `cd` into your `src` directory and then load the module from there.

Comment: If you try to compile with cabal, ghc will be directed to `.\src\MyLib\Data\Examples.hs` and expect a module named `MyLib.Data.Examples`

Comment: Should I name my file `MyLib.Data.Examples.hs` as well?

Comment: Also I'm open to changing my file structure/naming conventions. This question is to find out current best-practices in the Haskell community for developing. For instance, in Java I would get an IDE, create a main method, and let the IDE handle the classpath. In Ruby on Rails I would launch a local server configured to reload classes on every request. In Haskell, I would...?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Actually, since version 1.18 cabal comes with a neat `cabal repl` feature, which runs GHCI on the project, while resolving all the appropriate settings from the "cabal" file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essentially there are four approaches: writing tests, writing executables, experimenting with REPL (GHCI) and writing benchmarks. Luckily the latest Cabal (1.18) supports all of them. Also for reference I have a project, which [exhibits some](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/graph-db/tree/8066838d5b2feab630401cc76c8e604fd969d405).

### Tests

Probably the best approach when you have some feature you need to test is to write a unit-test. Accumulating tests with the growth of your project is the key to its reliability.

There are three main frameworks out there: [**HUnit**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit) for unit-testing, [**QuickCheck**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) for property-testing and [**doctest**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/doctest) for testing examples from doc comments. There also are dome frameworks, like [**HTF**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF), which unites HUnit and QuickCheck and relieves you from some of their boilerplate.

In Cabal you can define test-suites as separate compilation units with their own settings. [Here is an example](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/graph-db/blob/8066838d5b2feab630401cc76c8e604fd969d405/graph-db.cabal#L184). You can then run them with `cabal test`.

### Executables

There are some cases when testing does not really cover the requirements. A standard case is a program, which demonstrates, how the library is supposed to be used. [Here is an example](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/graph-db/blob/8066838d5b2feab630401cc76c8e604fd969d405/graph-db.cabal#L132).

You may also use executables as sandboxes for testing the APIs of your library, but again, a wiser approach is to write tests.

You can run executables with `cabal run [name]`, where the "name" specifies the executable name if there's a need to disambiguate (i.e., when you have more than one).

### REPL (GHCI)

The main benefit is it allows you to experiment with the APIs of your project's modules in a "live" mode, when you load internal modules, run their functions and reload them on updates. This might be useful for analysing the API, but I personally find the two approaches above covering most of what I may need from it.

You can run GHCI on your project with `cabal repl [name]`.

### Benchmarks

[**Criterion**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) is a single dominant library for benchmarking. Similar to the above you can declare your benchmark executables in cabal with the `benchmark [name]` block. You can then run them with `cabal bench`.

Comment: Thank you! This post is amazing and answers so many questions I had.

Comment: Personally I use ghci all the time while writing, for ad hoc testing and experimentation. I miss it terribly when developing in other languages. Nevertheless this is an excellent answer.